# Does making an attack while Hidden reveal your position to a blind & deaf creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, stealth, vision-and-light, hearing

The rules on attacking creatures from hiding are:

> When a creature can't see you, you have advantage on attack rolls against it. **If you are hidden–both unseen and unheard–when you make an attack, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses.**

**Is your location "given away" to a blind & deaf creature that otherwise has no way to percieve you normally? What about if it is not the one being attacked?**

(For clarity, the creature does not have truesight or blindsight or any other special senses. If it were next to you it could perceive you by touch, but in this situation it is not)

To that creature, you will be "unseen and unheard" before you make the attack, during it, and after it.

I think that this hinges on exactly what "give away your location" means. It could mean "all creatures in the combat know where you are", or it could mean "all creatures capable of perceiving you know where you are", or something else.

Comment: @PJRZ This question arose from the comments on this answer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/124975/42959 - essentially if a blind and deaf creature who is not even the one being attacked gets the location of a previously-hidden creature revealed to them when they attack out of hiding, then probably taking the Hide action is the only way for creatures to not know your location on the battlefield. On the other hand if that location is not revealed to that creature, then not seeing or hearing a creature might be sufficient to not know their exact location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, to an extent

The creature would certainly *feel* a successful attack despite being blind and deaf! A missed attack? Well, he may feel the 'whoosh' of a blade or arrow passing by but this could require some DM adjudication (perhaps a perception check at disadvantage but only if the creature is aware of a potential danger).

If this was a melee attack that would certainly be enough to give away a rough location. For a ranged attack this becomes much harder and as a DM I would rule that the creature would only know the rough direction that the attack came from but probably not the distance (and not enough for a ranged counter-attack).

Either way, the creature would certainly know that *someone* is out there trying to hurt them.

### If the creature was not the one being attacked:

In this case I can't really see how the creature - if they have no other sense at all - could possibly know the attacker is there (unless the attack happens close enough, and the creature is aware of potential danger, to maybe feel the 'whooshes' of swinging blades as described in the other case).

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer:

It's technically a null question, as all of the benefits of being hidden are already granted by the target being blinded. But to directly answer: **Yes**, as it is not explicitly noted as an exception to the general rule of revealing yourself when hidden, but it shouldn't affect things.

### Long answer:

There are a few parts of this to acknowledge. First I believe should be the benefits and situation of being hidden. The benefits of taking the Hide action and hiding is becoming unseen and unheard, by being quiet and ducking behind something, which grants you advantage against them as they can't see you, and them disadvantage to attack you (If they otherwise know you're there to logically attack you) because again, they can't see you (Basic rules, unseen attackers and targets). However, given the target is blind and deafened (Automatically failing sight and hearing based checks, as they can't see or hear) you don't need to take the hide action in the first place in regards to that creature, you are 'hidden' by default.

Overall, being 'hidden' is not really a condition, or anything with an affect. However, you are at all times unseen and unheard by a blind and deaf creature. Functionally the same as just being blinded, except they can't find your 'area' by hearing, as with Invisible creatures where they are assumed to be making readily-audible sounds unless a stealth check is made.

Now addressing the attack itself, attacking while hidden would reveal you, so anything capable of hearing or seeing (or otherwise sensing) would obviously spot you as normal, but the blind/deaf creature could be ruled a few ways because it isn't explicitly said, but two stand out to me as the most apt to use. Either one, it doesn't because it auto fails the supposed check to see an obvious, no-longer-hiding creature attacking, or two, it does reveal you but you are immediately hidden again because you are unseen and unheard. In either case, ultimately being 'hidden' itself is never technically it's own benefit, since it is only a path toward the benefit of being unseen while attacking, which is already covered by being blinded.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

## No, it would not.

That creature has no means to perceive you in general. If they can't see or hear you and do not have any special senses that would make them aware, then they are barely able to interact with the environment beyond touch as-is. Even if they 'felt' an attack (which would also be at advantage against them), they have no means of determining where that attack came from.