# Is being unseen an equivalent to being hidden?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, stealth, ranged-attack

For example, if I am using a longbow, and my party is ~50ft in front of me, and I have made no actions other then getting up to a high point, am I able to shoot with advantage, and if so, can I use the hide action?

If you look at a question such as [Does hidden just mean unseen and unheard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124989/does-hidden-just-mean-unseen-and-unheard), it talks about specific exceptions to how being hidden is being unseen and unheard, and I am not sure if this is an exception or not.

Comment: Is the question linked above the same as what you are asking? If not, how is it different?

Comment: Are you asking if being in plain sight, but unnoticed, still qualifies as being hidden?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose, yes, that has my answer

Comment: Just to be pedantic, you must be "un-percieved" - So any sense that can detect the character (Blindsight, tremorsense, etc.) would all negate the advantage.