# Does flying around on a broom of flying make sound?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Would flying around on a broom of flying make any sound?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. You may want to edit the question to include how this issue arose at your table (e.g. "The DM said I everyone could hear my invisible PC wooshing around on his flying broom"). More information is usually better. That said, thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 15):

### It neither makes sound nor masks sound

The Broom of Flying states:

> This wooden broom, which weighs 3 pounds, functions like a mundane broom until you stand astride it and speak its command word. It then hovers beneath you and can be ridden in the air. It has a flying speed of 50 feet. It can carry up to 400 pounds, but its flying speed becomes 30 feet while carrying over 200 pounds. The broom stops hovering when you land.
>
> You can send the broom to travel alone to a destination within 1 mile of you if you speak the command word, name the location, and are familiar with that place. The broom comes back to you when you speak another command word, provided that the broom is still within 1 mile of you.

**It’s description is silent as to if it’s silent.**

A person riding the broom can hide because nothing in the description says they can’t and they can be found by a creature who succeeds on a Perception check. They might be found because of the noise they or the broom makes or for any other reason.

An unridden broom can’t hide because it isn’t a creature although a creature could hide it, however, if it was moving by itself it would no longer be in that hiding place.

Each DM can decide if the broom makes noise from the limits of being absolutely silent to always singing arias. Personally, I would treat it like all the brooms that I have in my closet; when they aren’t hitting or scraping on something else they are silent, when they are, they aren’t.

**However, a person riding a broom is no more or less silent then they are when not riding it.**

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does one hide on a flying broom? I get it doesn't say you "can't hide", but that seems similar to it not having to be said you can't hide when in an empty hallway. Up to the DM, but having a hard time visualizing how to hide when flying around on a stick :)

Comment: @NautArch It's as context-dependent as anything else, but a flier could use a mundane visual barrier (a wall, a cloud, foliage, draping a camouflage-patterned length of cloth from it). Magic can also help, but more in the "is the invisible person riding the broom or somewhere else?" vein. I have a player who is constantly frustrated that his character can turn invisible but the broom can't.

Comment: @Upper_Case Ah! I may have read too much into that line then. DaleM may have simply meant that nothing prevents a rider of a broom to take the hide action rather than thinking something else.

Comment: @NautArch I suppose it was presumptuous of me to put in a comment like that on someone else's answer. I think I was just excited to share an instance of that player being frustrated with the broom, since it's complicated so many things on my end (to his delight).

Answer (score 5):

### A creature riding the broom will make noise

The [Broom of Flying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/broom-of-flying) states:

> This wooden broom, which weighs 3 pounds, functions like a mundane broom until you stand astride it and speak its command word. It then hovers beneath you and can be ridden in the air. It has a flying speed of 50 feet. It can carry up to 400 pounds, but its flying speed becomes 30 feet while carrying over 200 pounds. The broom stops hovering when you land.
>
> You can send the broom to travel alone to a destination within 1 mile of you if you speak the command word, name the location, and are familiar with that place. The broom comes back to you when you speak another command word, provided that the broom is still within 1 mile of you.

No part of its description describes it as making the rider silent, and so they are not silent. Similarly the section on [Unseen Attackers and Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnseenAttackersandTargets) states:

> [...] If you are hidden--both unseen and unheard--when you make an attack, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses.

This explains that being hidden (taking the Hide action) is how a creature becomes unheard. The Broom of Flying does not make you hidden, nor does it explicitly say that you are silent and thus you continue to make noise when flying.

Compare this with the [Boots of Elvenkind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/boots-of-elvenkind) which state:

> While you wear these boots, your steps make no sound, regardless of the surface you are moving across [...]

Overall this means that other creatures would still be able to locate you even while flying; your GM may say this is from the broom making noise, or perhaps a cloak or your armor. The reason other creatures could still locate you is because you are not hidden, something explained more in the following question:

- [In combat, do creatures have complete knowledge of the locations of all other non-Hidden creatures in the combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124957)

### Whether the broom is locatable and whether it makes noise when flying on its own is left up to your GM

The question linked above only deals with creatures knowing the location of other creatures, not with them knowing the location of objects. Additionally, objects (usually) cannot even take the Hide action and so cannot actually become Hidden. But what happens with objects in this sort of scenario is not defined in the rules so whether or not the broom makes noise and whether or not other creatures know the location of the broom is going to be left up to your GM.

Comment: Would the brooom of flying make enough sound such that enemies could target you(/identify where you are) while flying around and being invisible?

Comment: @Ralph I've added a bit at the end to address that. Their location would still be known (though your GM may always rule otherwise)

Comment: Are you saying the broom isn't silent or that the person riding it isn't silent?

Comment: @NautArch I *think* I've made an edit to account for it

Comment: I don't think the questions is asking "does ridding a broom *make* you silent" so much as "does a flying broom make noise" and "can riding on a broom help one be silent" - obviously it isn't magically making the rider not make noise, but neither is the broom making any noise. What the broom is doing though, is preventing the rider from having to move their body very much, or touch the ground or other objects in order to move. So the question is: could one use a broom of flying to *avoid* making noise. Which is up to the DM, but logically unless the broom itself makes noise... yes.