# Can a Firbolg standing behind a wall see without being seen?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, illusion, cover, firbolg

The Firbolg Magic trait says:

> **Firbolg Magic.** You can cast detect magic and disguise self spells with
> this trait. When you use this version of disguise self, you can seem
> up to 3 feet shorter or taller.

If the "seem" in this description wasn't clear enough, disguise self itself hammers home the concept that the change is purely optical.

> The changes wrought by this spell fail to hold up to physical
> inspection. For example, if you use this spell to add a hat to your
> outfit, objects pass through the hat, and anyone who touches it would
> feel nothing or would feel your head and hair.

**Does this mean a Firbolg can essentially make their real head invisible, being thus able to stand behind a wall tall enough to fully conceal their illusory form but with their real, invisible head poking out above?**

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not from what I can see from the two quoted descriptions, which is why I'm wondering if there's a clarification/erratum out there that I don't know about.

Comment: Partly related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101623/

Comment: Somewhat related: [If my Firbolg lifts a barrel over their head while appearing 3ft taller from their Disguise Self, where does the barrel appear?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/206115/23547)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### This works

Your quotations cover all the relevant rules. (Up to) Three feet of the Firbolg's height is not visible, so all they have to worry about hiding is the remaining part of their image.

Obviously, if an opponent has Truesight or the like, the Firbolg will look like an idiot trying to hide with three feet of them sticking over the top, but otherwise, it works exactly as you expect.

Comment: @JoakimM.H. They wouldn't be able to see the bits behind the wall, but the grinning, oblivious head of the Firbolg they definitely could.

Comment: @JoakimM.H.: That question covers the case of actual shapechanging (needing to spot the small current form to have a chance perceive the real form), but for the case of "illusion conceals part of body, which is still physically there", I think it's pretty clear truesight will work. It automatically detects visual illusions, and Disguise Self is just a visual illusion. It's not making the Firbolg any smaller, so the 3' of "real Firbolg" concealed by the illusion, if in line of sight, would be visible to anyone with truesight.

Answer (score 7):

### Let's be careful with words

The firbolg is *not* invisible, because invisible is a game term with a specific definition, and that definition is certainly not 'having part of them behind cover and the other part under an illusion'.  For example, they would *not* be revealed by a *[see invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/see-invisibility)* spell, but could be seen as normal (that is, the part not concealed by the wall) by a creature with *[truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Truesight)*.

Rather than say they are invisible, we can say that even though the firbolg can see, it is completely **unseen**.  It is unseen because part of its body is behind total cover / is concealed by an obstacle, and the part of its body that is not behind cover does not appear to be present because of their magical disguise.  Since they are unseen, if they were targeted, we would use the rules for [attacking and being attacked while unseen](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnseenAttackersandTargets).

Because the wall is concealing the part of them that can be seen, we could also say that they are [**heavily obscured**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight).  This largely overlaps with them being unseen, but in addition means that any skill check made against them that relies on sight would fail.

Finally, if we suppose the firbolg is actually 7' tall regardless of appearances, them more than half of it is behind the wall.  We would grant them **[three-quarters cover](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ThreeQuartersCover)**, but *not* total cover, to effects originating on the other side of the wall.  Their cover depends on their actual body, not their appearance.

Comment: Note. Fir in Old Irish is the nominative plural (so too in modern Irish and Scottish Gaelic), either that or the genitive singular. So you should be saying ‘fear bolg’ when you want the plain singular. How’s that for pedantry? The mistake probably arises because they were so often referred to in the plural.

Comment: Another fyi. The spelling system was different in OIr and nowadays we would spell this ‘fir bholg’ (nom. pl.), or ‘fear bolg’ (nom. sing.), and the ‘b’ now spelled ‘bh’ for clarity was and still is pronounced like a /v/. Back then it was perhaps bilabial, ie pronounced lip-to-lip, not labiodental, teeth-to-lip.

Comment: So /fir’ voLg/ for the nom. pl. and /fɛr voLg/ for the nom. sing. This would also be the pronunciation in modern Scottish Gaelic, although Irish dialects differ.

Comment: @CecilWard I have no reason to doubt your linguistic corrections, but note that in MMoP (their source in 5e), firbolg is used as the singular and firbolgs as the plural.